# select key after group

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I am trying to select all they keys after i perform a group-by. It works if I put the group into a variable then perform the select on the variable, but not directly after the group. I don't know why.

This does not work:

```
var pureUsers = from u in userContext.Users
    join ur in userContext.UserRoles on u.UserID equals ur.UserID
    join r in userContext.Roles on ur.RoleID equals r.RoleID
    join sm in userContext.SystemMasters on r.SystemMasterID equals sm.SystemMasterID
    where sm.SystemName == "PURE"
    group ur.UserRoleID by u.SAPID into g
    select g.Key;
```

It's giving me the error, "'string' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found"

However, it works like this:

```
var pureUsers = from u in userContext.Users
    join ur in userContext.UserRoles on u.UserID equals ur.UserID
    join r in userContext.Roles on ur.RoleID equals r.RoleID
    join sm in userContext.SystemMasters on r.SystemMasterID equals sm.SystemMasterID
    where sm.SystemName == "PURE"
    group ur.UserRoleID by u.SAPID

var happy = pureUsers.Select(x => x.Key);
```

I also tried:

```
var pureUsers = (from u in userContext.Users
    join ur in userContext.UserRoles on u.UserID equals ur.UserID
    join r in userContext.Roles on ur.RoleID equals r.RoleID
    join sm in userContext.SystemMasters on r.SystemMasterID equals sm.SystemMasterID
    where sm.SystemName == "PURE"
    group ur.UserRoleID by u.SAPID).Select(x => x.Key);
```

It gives me the same error. I don't see how this is any different than putting it into pureUsers then doing the select. Also, if there is a better way of doing this that doesn't involve a group-by, please tell me. I group it by SAPID because Users can have many UserRoles and I want a list of Users.SAPID where each SAPID is displayed once.

Comment: Instead of `group by` why not use `select` `Distinct()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
var pureUsers = (from u in userContext.Users
                 join ur in userContext.UserRoles on u.UserID equals ur.UserID
                 join r in userContext.Roles on ur.RoleID equals r.RoleID
                 join sm in userContext.SystemMasters on r.SystemMasterID equals sm.SystemMasterID
                 where sm.SystemName == "PURE"
                 select u.SAPID).Distinct();
```

Comment: For some reason, I didn't think Distinct() would work. I just got caught up in the wrong direction. I still don't know why it matters if you group it then set it in a variable or not before you select it.

Comment: @bobpal It should not. In my (LINQ to Objects) demo, it works fine either way.